# update all other records if one record changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sql-update, associations

I have two models `User` and `Motor` and each table has a `name` column. I have a user page where it shows all motors that users have.

The way I did it was so that the `name` column of the `Motor` table equals to the `name` column in the `User` table

```
Motor               User
name1               name1
name3               name2
name1               name3
name1               name4
name4               name5
```

So when looking into `name1`'s page, you'll see all the record of the `Motor` that has the name `name1`.

But when I wanted to update a name in the `User` table, how do I change all records in the `Motor` table that was supposed to be associated with the `user`?

So if I change `name1` to like `last1`, how do I change all `name1`'s to `last1` in `Motor` table?

This is my controller `show` method

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id]) 
  @motor = Motor.where(:name => @user.name)
end
```

Then I'm assuming I need to change my `update` method

```
if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
  if params[:name]
  # whats the correct way of changing all records that was previously the same name as user in the motor table?
  end
end
```

Thanks

Comment: This problem happens because your table is not normalized. Instead of saving user_name in Motor table save user_id. You can access user name by @model.user.name. This is the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a reason to do otherwise, I would recommend using a delegate. Here is how it would look:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :motors
end

class Motor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  delegate :name, :to => :user
end
```

Now if you were to call `@motor.name` then it would return the name of the user to which the motor belongs. This eliminates the need for the name column in the motor table and you don't need to update each motor's name when the user changes their name.

Comment: this would assume that there's an id column associated with the tables though right?

Comment: Yes, this solution assumes that a motor belongs to a user and therefore has a user_id column.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're doing it is not leveraging associations. What do your models look like? I think they should look something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :motors
end

class Motor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

When this is setup you can tie into the `after_save` callback.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :motors

  after_save :update_names

  private

  def update_names
    self.motors.each do |motor|
      motor.name = self.name
    end
    self.save!
  end
end
```

If there's no association between `User` and `Motor` you can probably just brute force it by finding all motors with the old name, and rename them.

```
old_user_name = @user.name
@user.name = params[:name]

@motors = Motor.where(name: old_user_name).all
@motors.each do |motor|
  motor.name = params[:name]
  motor.save!
end
```